# Loop through matrix vertically and diagonally

Tags: java, c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix (multidimensional array) and the index can only move downwards and diagonally as a result of a specific condition (movement is shown in the picture). How can we achieve this movement in C# or Java?

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code that you have tried already? And what do you mean "move" down the array? Should it return each value in that direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to create a function that can return the values in an, either down or diagonal direction; in C#

```
void PrintVertOrDiag(int x, int y, int[,] arr, int dir) {

    if (dir != 0 && dir != 1) {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid direction. 0=down, 1=diagonal");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
        if (dir == 0) {
            // down
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i + y, x]); // down
            if (i + y == arr.GetLength(0) - 1)
                break;
        }
        else {
            // diagonal
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i + y, i + x]); 
            if (i + y == arr.GetLength(0) - 1 || i + x == arr.GetLength(1) - 1)
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
int[,] mylist = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    {11,12,13,14,15},
    {16,17,18,19,20}
};

PrintVertOrDiag(0, 1, mylist, 1);

// outputs:
// 6
// 12
// 18
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use custom indexers:

```
public class DownwardsDirectionCollection<T>
{
   // Declare an array to store the data elements.
   private T[,] arr;
   private int currentYIndex = -1;

   public DownwardsDirectionCollection(int y, int x) {
       arr = new T[y, x];
   }

   // Define the indexer to allow client code to use [] notation.
   public T this[int i1, int i2]
   {
      get { 
          if (currentYIndex >= i1) throw new InvalidOperationException();
          currentYIndex = i1;
          return arr[i1,i2]; 
      }
      set { arr[i1,i2] = value; }
   }
}
```

Check this [net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ct46q3) for proof of execution.